# Need to know if this script is safe for PHP

Tags: javascript

I have PHP WordPress running and I am running custom theme shop based.
I have private message system and it required to press the refresh button on Firefox to see new messages, how ever I added this script at the bottom of private message PHP file:

```
<script>
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        $('#box_content')
            .fadeOut("slow")
            .load('/?jb_action=chat_boxx&oid=62')
            .fadeIn("slow");
    }, 10000);
</script>
```

and this just refreshes the content grabbed from other php file in server.

What I want to know is, if the private message is not browsed or navigated will this code run? meaning will this script run?

Or will it only run when that php page is viewed?

Comment: Why not try it?

Comment: i added it but need to know if it will kill resourse with un nessesary request ?